# Finding and checking values in an array in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a variable that outputs the result of validation in ReactJS as an array:

```
console.log(this.state.check); // [account: false, name: true, email: true]
```

Verification required:

- if all values in this variable are true - return true
- if one or more values are not equal to true - return false and one of the elements with the value false

I am new to ReactJS and my code is throwing an error

```
var check = this.state.check.map(item => item).some(item => item === true) ? true : false;
console.log(check); // error
```

I will be very grateful for the correct solution.

Comment: `[account: false, name: true, email: true]` isn't an array and is invalid. Did you mean `{ account: false, name: true, email: true }`?

Comment: V8 will output "[account: false, name: true, email: true]" for `let arr = []; arr.account = false; arr.name = true; arr.email = true; console.log(arr);`. However, this means the code producing the "array" is severely borked already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `Array.prototype.filter` function:

```
// Filter the array and get only the items that are false
// Returns an array of false items or an empty array
var falseProps = Object.entries(this.state.check).filter(([key, value]) => value === false);

// False props is now an array 
if(falseProps.length > 0) {
  // Do something if false
} else {
  // Do something if true
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! How can I deduce one of the elements with value false?

Comment: The elements with value `false` are all inside the `falseProps` array. You can get all or any of them using the usual array access methods. For example. to get the first element, you'd use `falseProps[0]`.

Comment: Thank you. Please help me again. How replace item in [account: false, name: true, email: true] ? This data can be filled in automatically in a different order, but I need to sort it so that first comes 'name', then the 'account' and then the 'email'. How can this be sorted?